# An application of Radon-Nicodym theorem

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, radon-nikodym

Consider $M$ be the $\sigma -$algebra of Lebesgue measurable sets and $\mu $
the Lebesgue measure. Denote by $P$ the set of $p-$measurable sets, that is
the sets $A\in \mathcal{P}\left(
\mathbb{R}
\right) $ such that the set
\begin{equation*}
\left\{ x\in \left[ 0,1\right] \mid 1+x^{2}\in A\right\}
\end{equation*}
is $M_{\left[ 0,1\right] \text{ }}-$measurable. Prove

(a) the function
\begin{equation*}
\nu :A\rightarrow \left[ 0,\infty \right] ,
\quad
\nu \left( A\right) =\mu \left( \left\{ x\in \left[ 0,1\right] \mid
1+x^{2}\in A\right\} \right)
\end{equation*}
is a complete measure and

(b) show that
$$
\int_{\left[ 0,\infty \right) }\sqrt{x}d\nu \left( x\right) =\int_{\left[ 0,1%
\right] }\sqrt{x^{2}+1}d\mu \left( x\right)
$$
and compute
$$
\int_{\left[ 0,\infty \right) }\sqrt{x}d\nu \left( x\right) .
$$
Let's say that for the part (a) is an easy verification of definitions: the image of the empty set is $0$, $\nu$ is countable additive and for all $Z$ in A with $\nu(Z)=0$, every subset of $Z$ lies in $A$. For the second part, I don't know how to apply the Radon-Nycodim theorem to prove the equality from b. I think that the last integral can be computed using the equality above and the fact that the RHS integral is equal with Riemann integral of the function $\sqrt{x^2+1}$ on $[0,1]$. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

By definition $\int f d\nu =\int f(1+x^{2})d\mu$ when $f=I_A$. This implies that the equation holds for simple functions and then for all non-negative Borel measurable functions, In particular it holds for $f(x)=\sqrt x$. Thus $\int \sqrt x d\nu =\int \sqrt {1+x^{2}} d\mu$. (Evaluation of $\int \sqrt {1+x^{2}} d\mu$ is standard: You can write it as $x\sqrt {1+x^{2}}|_0^{1}-\frac 1  2\int \frac x {\sqrt {1+x^{2}}} d\mu (x)$ and then make the substitution $y=1+x^{2}$).

Comment: I am a bit confused. There is no need of the Radon-Nycodym theorem here or it is hidden somewhere in your argument? And by $I_A$ you denoted the characteristic function of $A$ or something else? Do you have a reference book for "by definition ...."?

Comment: $I_A$ is  the characteristic function of $A$. There is no need for RNT. $\int I_A g(x) d\mu(x)=\int_A g(x)d\mu(x)$. This is the definition of $\int_A g(x)d\mu(x)$. You are just over thinking and the enitire argument is very elementary not requiring any theorem.  @stefano

Comment: Probably is an easy computation, but I don't understand what was used in the following remark: "you can write it as $x\sqrt {1+x^{2}}|_0^{1}-\frac 1  2\int \frac x {\sqrt {1+x^{2}}} d\mu (x)$ ". Why is $-\frac 1  2\int \frac x {\sqrt {1+x^{2}}} d\mu (x)$ and not $-\int \frac 2x^2 {\sqrt {1+x^{2}}} d\mu (x)$ ? Or is not the same as integration by parts in the Riemann integral?

Comment: $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure. Riemann integral and integral w.r.t $\mu$ coincide.  @stefano